# C how to print short ints stored in char array?

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy

I have an char array and stored short ints in it:

```
char buf[50];
short int num = 12;
```

filled it up with memcpy:

```
memcpy(buf, &num, 50);
```

and then i am trying to print that out:

```
for(i=0; i <50;i++) {
    printf("%hd|",buf[i]);
}
```

I think `%hd` should be the right specifier to print that out. But my output is the following:

> 12|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|12|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|12|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|12|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|12|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|12|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|12|0|

It seems that their are 7 Byte Space between my content(*12*). But i want to store the *"12"* in every single byte. It should be possible to store and short in a char array, i mean the max representation of 1 byte is 256. What i am doing wrong? ... looking for some good advice =)

Developing under linux.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski, the destination is buf, not num

Comment: Did you compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)? If you did, the compiler would have warned you!

Comment: I didn't get any warning mhh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `memcpy` you should use [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/).

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[50];
    int i;
    short int num = 12;
    memset(buf,num,50);

    for(i=0; i <50;i++) 
    {
        printf("%hd|",buf[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I knew it.. that my mistake should be more then obvious.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong function: `memcpy` instead of `memset`.
Quoting `man(3) memcpy`:

> The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.

This would be ok if num were a buffer with at least n bytes. However, you want to set a single value to a certain chunk of memory:
`memset(buff, 12, sizeof(buff))`.

Answer (score 1):

As,

`memset()` sets all of the bytes in the specified buffer to the same value, `memcpy()` copies a sequence of bytes from another place to the buffer.

so you should use `memset()` instead of `memcpy()` function.

so just change

```
memcpy(buf, &num, 50);
```

to

```
memcpy(buf, num, 50);
```

so your final code will be ..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[50];
    int i;
    short int num = 12;
    memset(buf,num,50);

    for(i=0; i <50;i++) printf("%hd|",buf[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`filled it up with memcpy()`. Wrong. `memcpy()` won't fill the array. Check the proper usage of `memcpy()` in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy).

You need to use a loop to put the value into the array. Otherwise, you can initialize the array (have a look at [`memset()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) ) to hold the value.